# How to prevent CSS caching on a web page?

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, css, xhtml

I am learning to develop xhtml, css web pages. Often I am doing changes in CSS but it do not reflect on page because of browser cacheing and if I manually clear cahceing it shows latest code effects. Is there a thing I can put in code to make browker not to cache stuff ? Any advice please

Comment: This question goes over the many meta tags to prevent caching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers but your best bet is modifying the headers returned from the server.

Comment: if you are doing this for development purposes, better turn off cache, what browser are you using ?

Comment: @Matthew: Good tip, you should add this as an answer. Downside of course - you turn of all caching on the page, not just the CSS.

Comment: @Matthew: no, I think the best bet for development purposes is to disable caching on the browser instead of messing with server settings.

Comment: @frenchie: As always, that really depends on your scenario. There are cases where changing the html might be better. If you are testing browser compability for example, you would have to change settings in all browsers then. Or if you are showing the page to different people on different PCs.

Comment: I just mean that the meta tag method to disable caching might not be reliable depending on the browser.

Answer (score 63):

You can append a random query parameter to the stylesheet url (for example via javascript or server side code). 
It will not change the css file that is being loaded, but it will prevent caching, because the browser detects a different url and will not load the cached stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mysite/style.css?id=1234">
```

Comment: Thank you. Just saved me a lot of time and hassle. +1

Comment: function rs( $length = 8 ) {
  $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  $rs = substr( str_shuffle( $chars ), 0, $length );
  return $rs;
 }

Comment: Is this still relative in 2022?

Comment: @Abregre I have the feeling it isn't. Conform the comments to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1614568/12068558

Comment: It is still valid. The important part is that you actually use a random parameter and not just the same every time.

Answer (score 9):

You can create class with GetVersion method which will return your application version (or for example build number or build date).

For asp.net application in markup you can then specify something like this:

```
<script src="Scripts/some.js?version=<%= Common.GetVersion%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/styles/Style.css?version=<%= Common.GetVersion%>" />
```

This will force browser to reload files because part of URL to static files will be changed every build (or at least every version).

Comment: very nice idea, that way you have caching that gets "reset" when you push a new build

Answer (score 7):

With no catching:
Put changeable strings at the end of css path, as bellow:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?2016-12-3:10 13 30"/>
```

Refresh when version changes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?v=1.1.0"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Chrome as your development browser, there are 2 options:

1) When you hold the *reload page* button down for a second, a menu will appear and offer the possibility to do a hard page reload.

2) In the Inspector settings, you can force the browser to never cache files.

[image]

I think it's easier, faster and less trouble to handle this issue by disabling caching on the browser than in the server configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Since the ASP.net tag is also included in the question, I'd like to expand on Maxim Kornilov's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12992813/903783) with how I used his idea of making the URLs webapp-build-specific on ASP.net MVC (his example was in ASP/ASP.net WebForms syntax instead of MVC's and Razor Pages' newer Razor syntax):

1) Added to the webapp's main class (was called MvcApplication) in Global.asax.cs

```
#region Versioning

public static string Version => typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString(); //note: syntax requires C# version >=6

public static DateTime LastUpdated => File.GetLastWriteTime(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly.Location);

#endregion
```

the someProperty => someReadOnlyExpression syntax is just shorthand for someProperty { get { return ... ;} } possible since C# 6

2) in its Content/_Layout.cshtml file I used to have the following to show build number and build datetime (based on the webapp's main assembly) on the page footer:

```
Version @ViewContext.Controller.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version (@string.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd-HH:mm:ss}", @File.GetLastWriteTime(ViewContext.Controller.GetType().Assembly.Location)))
```

which I changed to the simpler:

```
Version @somewebappname.MvcApplication.Version (@string.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd-HH:mm:ss}", somewebappname.MvcApplication.LastUpdated))
```

3) it was loading the CSS via hardcoded link in _Layout.cshtml (still refactoring it) which I changed to:

```
<link href='@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css?version=" + somewebappname.MvcApplication.Version)' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

so if one right-clicks in the webpage and they do view source they see:

```
<link href='/Content/Site.css?version=2.1.5435.22633' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

that is the CSS url is version specific thanks to the dummy parameter version

If a random number was used instead it would fetch the CSS at every page load which is usually undesired, especially if you are already pushing a new webapp build instead of individual page changes to the web server (so that you do have access to a build number that you can inject into URLs).

Note that to achieve auto-incrementing of build number, at Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs I have (see [How to have an auto incrementing version number (Visual Studio)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826777/how-to-have-an-auto-incrementing-version-number-visual-studio)):

```
// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Revision and Build Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
//[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.*")] //don't use boh AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion with auto-increment
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done through a .htaccess file. Place this code in a file named .htaccess at the root of your website:

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: This is if you don't want to manually refresh the cache every time.

Comment: This won't work in asp.net; that's not how headers work in the framework.

Comment: asp.net has a similar mechanism, but using web.config instead

Answer (score 1):

instead of writing  `<link>` tag  using html just use php code. inside `<link>` tag at the end use php `mt_rand()` function which will produce a random number and thus your stylesheet will never get cached.
`<?php 
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css?'".mt_rand().">";
?>`

Comment: it should be echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css?".mt_rand()."'>";

Answer (score 0):

You can use random version id in your link. for example use this:

```
<link   href=<%="'mystyle.css?version="+ DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") +"'"%>   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

where myStyle.css is stylesheet file and DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") function used for generate random different version id.
By using this random version id,browser forced to reload your css.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Google Chrome simply press CTRL + F5 to force said refresh. The CSS will be updated to how it is on your local machine or server. You can also use a .htaccess file, but that is more of a permanent solution to a possibly temporary problem. CSS caching is good for faster page loading, so I do not recommend disabling it entirely.

Answer (score -4):

- Press F12 on the chrome to open the developer tool
- Then right-click on the reload button - Click (Clear Cache and Hard Reload)

Comment: Actually ctrl + F5 forces the browser to clear the cache in every browser I know of (mobile excluded obviously).

Comment: in common browsers, pressing it once after the page has loaded should be enough to refresh the page's cache

Comment: Ankush Jain I am doing same now but I dont want it every time and want some way I may dont have to do this every time and by default browser may not do it.

Comment: Pressing just `F5`, `Ctrl+R` or `GUI Refresh button` might won't change anything. Consider pressing(Google Chrome) `Shift+F5`, `Ctrl+Shift+R` or `Shift+ GUI Refresh button`. Also, would you really directly ask the user to force clear the cache? More info: https://www.ghacks.net/2018/01/24/google-chrome-hard-reload-vs-normal-reload/#:~:text=You%20activate%20the%20function%20with,from%20the%20web%20page%20again Depends on browser, though.

Comment: @AnkushJain You are able to edit your answers. Thus, are you trolling? It's really sad then.

Comment: @F8ER - Updated.