# Website behaving differently on IE9 on one domain, but exact same site on different domain behaves fine

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-9, behavior

I'm majorly struggling to find out the cause behind this.
The website functions completely fine on firefox, IE10 (and above), safari, etc. but on IE9 (and possibly lower versions), the website style doesn't function properly.

i used two domains, on one the website functions fine, while on the other domain, i have uploaded the exact same files and it doesn't function properly.

ill provide you with both URL's
http://www.cilnet.com  - not behaving properly on IE9
http://www.microlinkcilnet.com/cilnet - EXACTLY the same website - behaves properly on IE9

here is an image that differences both the sites
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehqnI.jpg

your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Both these URLs look identical for me.. though I'm using IE10 in IE9 mode.  Caching issue maybe? One of your servers could be set up to cache images/CSS files and the other not?

Comment: ..suggest adding a dummy parameter to the CSS file that contains the styles in question eg.. <filename>.CSS?r=242342 to force a reload.

Answer (score 0):

Its caching issure as WindsorAndy wrote.

press crtl+F5 once or twice to see the updated background colors that you added to the css.

refer to [How to prevent css caching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12992803/1166597)

Also prevent all cache with random number would mean `you gain no benefit at all from browser caching which would be horrendous for performance`.

You'd be better off doing something like adding a version number to the end of the file name like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?version=1.12` that you update version as needed.

Comment: thanks, i have tried this, but no success. i dont want to have to disable caching for the site. i dont understand why it works on one domain but not the under, its all on the same server.

Comment: It was working fine with us for both links, you may try different browsers that you didn't use before or try different machine to see for your self that the sites are working fine.