# CSS is only working when I put it in <style> tag, not in external file

Tags: html, css

I was trying to add, CSS to a `<form><select><option></option</select></form>` html. But it only works, when i put the CSS in  tag in  tag. Not when, i put the same thing in externl file.

Yes I link external file correctly. Other CSS in the external file is working perfectly, but no this. What could possible go wrong?

Edit: Just found, the page got cached, CSS was working. But, i don't even know, how to cache a page? How my website got cached?

Comment: You should probably delete this question or otherwise completely rewrite it to focus on your issue of page caching (although it's probably a duplicate)

Comment: see this related post: [how to how to prevent css caching on a web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992717/how-to-prevent-css-caching-on-a-web-page)

Comment: Just use Shift+F5 while developing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it could resolves the problem of cache

```
 <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" /> 
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" /> 
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" /> 
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1994 1:00:00 GMT" /> 
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```