# exclude specific css file on Google Cloud CDN

Tags: google-cloud-platform, caching, browser-cache, cache-control, google-cloud-cdn

Is a WordPress setup. I need to work on a css stylesheet but the changes do not reflect immediately. It will sometime reload the previous version too. How can I exclude a specific css file from caching while doing development work?

There is no caching enabled on the server.

[image]

Tried with versioning but it doesn't work.

```
wp_enqueue_style('child-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include a timestamp in the file name to prevent a particular CSS file from being cached while you are working on development. This will guarantee that the file is always up to date and that any modifications you make will immediately appear in your browser. You can, for instance, change the name of your CSS file from "style.css" to "style_[timestamp].css," where "timestamp" represents the current date and time. By doing this, you can get around any caching that might be in place and make sure that your changes show up right away. You can get assistance in resolving this problem by referring to [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40943563/19230181) and [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12992803/19230181).

Comment: Thanks. Before posting this question, I've tried adding  versioning to the style.css but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you look at SO1 and SO2 , and This [doc](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching) might give some information

Comment: Can you tell me where your problem is at and if the document above is helpful to you? Post any errors you find here.