# @font-face won't display on standard Chrome but will on Canary

Tags: google-chrome, font-face

What could be the reason for a web page to render without @font-face (until any zoom command, or invoking DevTools window)? The very same page will render just perfect on Canary, FF, IE.... The fonts are imported using the css code delivered by the fast.fonts.com service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be related to this bug report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336476.
It says that the problem may occur when modifying a style sheet while the font is still loading.

Also, see this question for some possible temporary workarounds: [@font-face Text is invisible in Chrome on refresh... but not always?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948022/font-face-text-is-invisible-in-chrome-on-refresh-but-not-always)

Comment: Thanks for the latter reference with a sneaky css fix. Will try substitute my jQuery workaround with this one.