# Why use "?ver=2.70" in css or script route?

Tags: javascript, html, css, version

Why do some people write this:

```
shop/js/uds-jsonp.js?ver=2.70
```

instead of

```
shop/js/uds-jsonp.js
```

I have checked the resource with `?ver=2.70` or without `?ver=2.70` and I did not see any differences.

Comment: It's to avoid problems with the browser keeping a cached version of the script. Cache lookups are based on the complete URL, so if the version number changes the browser will not find the script in its cache.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is style.css?ver=1 tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614429/what-is-style-cssver-1-tag)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is for [cache busting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params), if you change the version (the `ver` URI parameter) when a user loads the page `uds-jsonp.js` will be reloaded and not loaded from cache, ensuring the latest version is served.